# Unable to find java executable. Check JAVA_HOME ... while starting Cassandra

Tags: java, linux, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

***Running Cassandra***

```
$ apache-cassandra-3.11.1/bin/cassandra -f -R
Unable to find java executable. Check JAVA_HOME and PATH environment variables.
```

***Java Settings are***

```
java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_121"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Zulu 8.20.0.5-linux64) (build 1.8.0_121-b15)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Zulu 8.20.0.5-linux64) (build 25.121-b15, mixed mode)

whereis java
java: /usr/bin/java /usr/lib/java /etc/java /usr/share/java /data/ytbigdata/anaconda3/bin/java

which java
~/anaconda3/bin/java

~/.bash_profile setting
export JAVA_HOME=/data/ytbigdata/anaconda3/bin/java
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: What distribution of linux are you using? And what do you see if you do `ls /usr/share/java`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cassandra documentation says "On the Cassandra nodes where the agents are installed, create the file /etc/default/datastax-agent and set the environment variables for JAVA_HOME and any other custom environment variables that the agent might need."  https://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/6.1/opsc/install/opscCustomVariables_t.html